# How to use custom metric with specific filter in Horizontal Pod Autoscaling

Tags: kubernetes, autoscaling, nginx-ingress

I am trying to setup HPA for Ingress Controller based on custom metric *nginx_ingress_controller_nginx_process_connections_total*.

But while fetching the metrics from localhost:10254/metrics, I could see three such metrics with filter as follows:

```
# HELP nginx_ingress_controller_nginx_process_connections_total total number of connections with state {active, accepted, handled}
# TYPE nginx_ingress_controller_nginx_process_connections_total counter
nginx_ingress_controller_nginx_process_connections_total{controller_class="nginx",controller_namespace="ingress-nginx",controller_pod="nginx-ingress-controller-7dddd-mssssf",state="accepted"} 479707
nginx_ingress_controller_nginx_process_connections_total{controller_class="nginx",controller_namespace="ingress-nginx",controller_pod="nginx-ingress-controller-7dddd-mssssf",state="active"} 3
nginx_ingress_controller_nginx_process_connections_total{controller_class="nginx",controller_namespace="ingress-nginx",controller_pod="nginx-ingress-controller-7dddd-mssssf",state="handled"} 479707
```

Out of these metrics, I want to use the below metric for HPA.

```
nginx_ingress_controller_nginx_process_connections_total{controller_class="nginx",controller_namespace="ingress-nginx",controller_pod="nginx-ingress-controller-7dddd-mssssf",state="active"}
```

How can I use the specified metric from these different values. My yaml file for HPA is given below.

```
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta1
metadata:
  name: ingress-hpa
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    kind: Deployment
    name: nginx-ingress-controller
  minReplicas: 3
  maxReplicas: 10
  metrics:
  - type: Pods
    pods:
      metricName: <I need to set the custom metric here>
      targetAverageValue: 10000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use HPA custom metrics. You need to expose endpoint in POD to fetch the metrics also setup Prometheus and custom metric api server.